# Technique to make acrylic paint dry faster?

Tags: painting, paint, acrylic-paint, canvas, drying

My studio is in the basement of my house which is quite humid and there's no sunshine. As a result, it takes a long time for me to wait for my acrylic paintings to dry (one hour plus). Any suggestions on how to get the paint to dry quicker?

Answer (score 3):

Acrylic paints are already among the quickest drying paints there are and one hour really doesn't seem that much to me. Can't you just let the painting sit around for an hour undisturbed to dry? That seems like the easiest solution.

You wrote in a different post that you use a hair dryer to speed up the drying. The first idea is to point the hair dryer at the back of the canvas instead of the front with the wet paint. That way you still blast dust around, but you don't blast it directly at the wet paint. You could also tip the canvas so the wet front is angled down during the drying process. Any dust particle floating around has less of a chance to land on a downward-facing surface.

Apart from that, painting with dryer paints (less water / medium) obviously speeds up the drying, but certain techniques like wet-on-wet blending require a certain amount of moisture to work.

The next best idea is to put the painting in a different environment to dry. That can be as simple as taking it into another room with less humidity and letting it sit there until it dries naturally.

Comment: The last suggestion is spot on... it may also eliminate the dust problem from your other question.

Answer (score 2):

If your studio is humid, it may well benefit from a dehumidifer, to actually remove water from the air.

As these usually have a dust filter on the inlet, you could in theory direct the dry, slightly warm, output directly at the painting, but I suggest you don't. Instead rely mainly on drying the room a bit, and position things so the dehumidifier's fan gives you airflow around the painting.

If it's very humid in there, materials stored against the cold walls or floor may suffer from the damp. A dehumidifier would help with that too.